# VC++ decoding diacritics characters from stream

Tags: c#, visual-c++, character-encoding, socket.io

I have a small application client/server app. Client app(C#), server side(VC++). My application will send any character to server side using streams; english characters works fine except non-english. VC++ is using CString to accept this data from stream. I fix some of diacritics characters to read correctly when received but some of it won't work.
Client side encoded this characters using UnicodeEncoding() before sending it. It works fine on characters  É, À, È, Ù, Â, Ê, Î, Ô, Û, Ë, Ï, Ö, Ü except on Ÿ(this one will read as x_ on server side) and Turkish character are read incorrectly.

**Questions:**

- What should I add on my server side to handle diacritics characters such as Chinese/Russian/Turkish..etc?
- On Client side; should UnicodeEncoding() enough to encode properly those diacritics characters? Or other characters should be encoded differently?

A sample code would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a sample code would be of a great help. That is, a sample of what you have written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumble with the same problem.

Here's how I resolve my problem.
On client side

```
if (IsUnicode(str))
{
   writer.Write((uint)str.Length + 1);
   writer.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str));
}

private bool IsUnicode(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return false;

        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            if (c > 0x7F)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

On server side
Convert the string using CW2A with CP_UTF8 parameter

```
CStringA str = CW2A(m_CString, CP_UTF8);
m_CString.Format(_T("%s"), str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works.  So the data is being changed or somewhere a buffer isn't being flushed.  My usual recommendations is to check the byte count and see where the byte count is being changed.  Usually it is a stream class that isn't being set to unicode.

```
            string input = "ÉÀÈÙÂÊÎÔÛËÏÖÜŸ";
            byte[] temp = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
            string output = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(temp);
```

Comment: Yes I tried that and it works in C# but sending that byte[] to VC++ through stream missed up some characters when decoding it.

Comment: I would use UTF8 encoding to send the byte[] (not unicode) through a stream.